# Converter um número decimal em binário em linguagem LISP

Tags: lisp, números-binários

Levando em conta que é preciso dividir o número por 2 até ele ser igual a 1, e reorganizar os restos, como poderia ser feito esta conversão em LISP?

Comment: Olá user, não tenho certeza sobre o que você precisa, um inteiro é um inteiro indiferente de sua representação. Geralmente apenas queremos formatar o número (em uma *string*) em determinada base. Se for esse o caso, em Common Lisp basta usar a função [format](http://l1sp.org/cl/format) - `(format nil "~B" 42) = "101010"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supondo que seja um exercício que precise seguir o raciocínio do enunciado, seguem dois exemplos retirado [desta página](http://www.lispforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=688):

```
(defun dtb (x &optional (callback #'princ))
  (unless (= x 0)
    (dtb (floor x 2) callback)
    (funcall callback (mod x 2))))
```

e

```
(defun dtb-collect (x)
  (declare (type fixnum x))
  (do ((x x (floor x 2))
       (list nil (cons (mod x 2) list)))
      ((= x 0) list)))
```

Vide comentário do [@AnthonyAccioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/100/anthony-accioly) se não precisar do loop conforme descrito no corpo da pergunta:

> "Se for esse o caso, em Common Lisp basta usar a função format": (`format t "~B~%" 42`) = "101010"

Link demonstrativo, também gentilmente cedido pelo Anthony: http://ideone.com/WWg18G

Comment: Oi Bacco, deixa aí, o comentário é auto-contido hehehe. Só um exemplo para complementar a ideia [link para o Ideone](http://ideone.com/WWg18G).

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira para converter um número em binário é estar utilizando a função [**format**](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node200.html)(*como citado no comentário do [AnthonyAccioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17705/converter-um-numero-decimal-em-binario-em-linguagem-lisp#comment33518_17705)*) que é comparável ao [**printf**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) do **C**.

```lisp
(format t "~{~&~B~}" '(1 2 10 42 11)) ; 1 2 10 42 11 são os números a converter
```

O `~B` é parecido com `~D`, mas imprime em base binária (*base 2*) em vez de decimal.

[**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/9cKYSt)